# Multiple error_log locations for Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

Is there a way I can define multiple `Error_Log` locations in the apache configuration (logging the same error in 2 or more log files / pipes), or do I have to use a pipe & custom script to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log **errors** to [**syslog**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errorlog); this provides more flexibility than logging to a single file, since syslog allows you to write as many files as you want.

Comment: Hm, problem there is i lose the 'easy per (virtualh)host or per dir' locations, or I have to manualle parse that out again. Any quick solution for that that you know of?

Comment: I guess it's one or the other.

Comment: Does this mean that there isn't a way to have multiple ErrorLog entries in an Apache config?

Comment: Yes. There is only one *error*log per vhost, maximum.